# How can i check the details of my photos clicked by nikon 5100

Tags: metadata, camera-settings

I recently bought a Nikon D5100. Now I want to check the settings(shutter speed, f-stop, ISO etc. ) of my shots. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: In-camera or on a computer?

Comment: If on a computer - what operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Most of them you can retrieve on Windows by right-clicking the image and opening the `Properties`. Then, in the `Details` tab, you can find most of the metadata.

Not all the EXIF data is visible on that tab, though. You can find more by using a library manager like Picasa, ViewNX, Lightroom, or the like.

Answer (score 1):

For reading exif data stored in images, I'm in love with [ExifTool by Phil Harvey](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

It's a command-line application, so for most of it's functions you either need to write a bat file or use it from the command prompt.

It's still an easy way to check a pictures metadata without getting technical though as you can use it to quickly check a files information in the following way:
Windows instructions:

1. Download Windows Executable zip file from http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/
2. Extact the "exiftool(-k).exe" application to somewhere on your computer
   [image: Exiftool icon]
3. Drag the image that you want to analyse and drop it onto the "exiftool(-k).exe" icon
   [image: Image file being dropped on exiftool application]

This will cause a window to open detailing all the metadata in the file. To close the window, press any key.

[image: Screenshot of file exif information]

(My text is green, but by default yours would be grey)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, on Mac the Preview application can shows EXIF information (the information about how and when the photo was taken).

Launch preview, then go to tools > inspector (or press cmd-i).

The second tab, with the little (i) symbol, is the information, which has tabs that will show you exif info and other information based on file type.

Answer (score 0):

In camera, when reviewing shots on the LCD, press up or down on the d-pad to cycle through several different views, including highlight clipping and, helpfully for you, a screen showing the shot settings and histogram.